# iOS - UIBezierPath making start angle always vertical

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, uibezierpath

[image]

Hi I'm currently trying to make random angles of a circle but id like the startangle to always be vertical. In the image above its shows 180 degrees of a circle but the start angle is horizontal and it changes depending on the angle i specify. So basically i want the start of the circle to always start at 0 degrees or vertical. Does anyone know the solution for this?

This is the code I'm using.

```
let center = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 200, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
path.addLineToPoint(center)
path.closePath()

let angleShape = SKShapeNode(path: path.CGPath)
angleShape.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.203, green: 0.596, blue: 0.858, alpha: 1.0)
angleShape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.203, green: 0.596, blue: 0.858, alpha: 1.0)
addChild(angleShape)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 200, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 180.degreesToRadians, clockwise: true)
```

to this:

```
path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 200, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI_2), clockwise: true)
```

if you want a random `startAngle` and `endAngle` try this

```
func randomRange(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    assert(min < max)
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (max - min) + min
}

let startAngle = randomRange(min: CGFloat(0), max: CGFloat(M_PI*2))
let endAngle = randomRange(min: CGFloat(0), max: CGFloat(M_PI*2))

path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: 200, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks that does work but my end goal is to be able to put a constant into the endangle that generates a random number between 0-360. Is this possible?

Comment: ok ive edited my answer.  and you cant use degrees for this stuff..  its all in radians.  unless youre going to convert degrees to radians, but its not really worth the effort.